# Simple C program produces Blank Ouput - No Errors

Tags: c, string, declaration

I have a C program, which converts an input integer number, into the equivalent string, a character array. For example the integer 245 should be '2', '4', '5', '\0'. And the integer -493 should be '-', '4', '9', '3', '\0'. 
It is the exercise 14, of Chapter 10, in the book: Programming in C (third edition), by Stephen Kochan.
My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void ){

int integer = 245;

const char stringIntegers[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
int i = 0, j = 0;
char tempInt[10], stringInt[10];


// Checks whether the input integer is negative in order to store a '-', in [0] of the output string
if ( integer < 0 ){
    stringInt[0] = '-';
    j = 1;
    integer = -integer;
}

// extract digits of the input integer and store them, in opposite order (last to first digit), in temporary string
while ( integer ){
    tempInt[i] = stringIntegers[integer % 10];
    integer /= 10;
    ++i;
}

// now store them in the right order to output string
for( --i; i < 0; ++j, --i )
    stringInt[j] = tempInt[i];

// Finally, copy the null zero terminator to output string
stringInt[j] = '\0';


printf("%s\n", stringInt );

return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.014 s Press any key to
continue.
```

As you can see the output is blank. Compiler shows no errors, or warnings. This means that I must have some kind of logical error, but I have checked my code to the letter and I can't find a logical error. Except if it is an other kind of error like a definition of a string variable, an array (or such stuff that confuse me a bit). If anyone could help me, I would be most grateful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: BTW `char tempInt[10], stringInt[10];` is small for int32_t(-2147483648...2147483647)

Comment: Regardless of the size (BP you are correct by the way) you should **initialize** you arrays `char tempInt[10] = {0}, stringInt[10] = {0};`. Especially when working with character arrays. While you null-terminate properly below, filling them with null-terminators to begin with is always good practice.

Comment: So, initialize all arrays, especially strings. Got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) condition is the condition under which the loop continues, so :

```
for( --i; i < 0; ++j, --i )
```

should be :

```
for( --i; i >= 0; ++j, --i )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for( --i; i < 0; ++j, --i )
```

is supposed to be

```
for( --i; i >= 0; ++j, --i )
```

Otherwise, the loop never executes and you set the NUL-terminator in the first slot of `stringInt`. Hence,the `printf` prints nothing, but a newline.

Answer (score 1):

```
for( --i; i < 0; ++j, --i )
    stringInt[j] = tempInt[i];
```

You have a logical issue. This loop is executed when the condition `i < 0` is met but the condition is never met as your `i` is supposed to be `>= 0` in your program.